# Sort Records comparing sums across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I am wanting to bring back all jobs where

```
(
  SUM(Order.InvoicesReceived) > (SUM(Estimate.GrossValue) + SUM (AdditionalEstimate.GrossValue))
) OR ( 
    SUM(Order.ContractGiven) > (SUM(Estimate.GrossValue) + SUM (AdditionalEstimate.GrossValue))
)

CREATE TABLE Job (id INT, userid INT)
INSERT INTO Job ( id ,userid)VALUES  ( 1,1)    
INSERT INTO Job ( id ,userid)VALUES  ( 2,1)    
INSERT INTO Job ( id ,userid)VALUES  ( 3,2)  
INSERT INTO Job ( id ,userid)VALUES  ( 4,2)  
INSERT INTO Job ( id ,userid)VALUES  ( 5,1)  

CREATE TABLE [User] (id INT, UserName NVARCHAR (30))
INSERT INTO [User] ( id ,UserName)VALUES  ( 1,'Richard')
INSERT INTO [User] ( id ,UserName)VALUES  ( 2,'Jane')    

CREATE Table Estimate (id INT, [job] INT, [GrossValue] DECIMAL (18,2))
INSERT INTO Estimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 1,3, 100)  
INSERT INTO Estimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 2,4, 100)  
INSERT INTO Estimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 3,5, 200)  
INSERT INTO Estimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 4,5, 200)  

CREATE Table AdditionalEstimate (id INT, [job] INT, [GrossValue] DECIMAL (18,2))  
INSERT INTO AdditionalEstimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 1,1, 100)  
INSERT INTO AdditionalEstimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 2,2, 100)  
INSERT INTO AdditionalEstimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 3,5, 100)  
INSERT INTO AdditionalEstimate ( id ,[job], GrossValue)VALUES  ( 4,5, 100)

CREATE Table [Order] (id INT, [job] INT, ContractGiven DECIMAL (18,2), InvoicesReceived DECIMAL (18,2))
INSERT INTO [Order] ( id ,[job], ContractGiven,InvoicesReceived)VALUES  ( 1,1, 50, 0)  
INSERT INTO [Order] ( id ,[job], ContractGiven,InvoicesReceived)VALUES  ( 2,2, 150, 0)  
INSERT INTO [Order] ( id ,[job], ContractGiven,InvoicesReceived)VALUES  ( 3,3, 50, 0)  
INSERT INTO [Order] ( id ,[job], ContractGiven,InvoicesReceived)VALUES  ( 4,4, 150, 0)  
INSERT INTO [Order] ( id ,[job], ContractGiven,InvoicesReceived)VALUES  ( 5,5, 400, 0)  
INSERT INTO [Order] ( id ,[job], ContractGiven,InvoicesReceived)VALUES  ( 6,5, 100, 0)
```

To make it easy to see what results I should get I added the following table and updated the inserts into tables.

```
JOB Estimate AddEstimate Order  
1   Null     100         50    
2   Null     100         150  
3   100      NULL        50  
4   100      NULL        150  
5   200      100         500  
5   200      100         NA
```

`InvoicedRecieved` is ignored for simplicity. Jobs 2,4 Should be returned.

```
Richard 1, Jane 1
```

I also need another statement bring back the number of jobs per user that met the above criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon was correct about the need to sum before comparing, due to the Cartesian product. However as his query isn't producing the correct result here is the query which does.

```
select J.id [Job]
  , coalesce(O.InvoicesReceived,0) InvoicesReceived
  , coalesce(O.ContractGiven,0) ContractGiven
  , coalesce(E.GrossValue,0) + coalesce(A.GrossValue,0) TotalQuoteCost
from Job J
left join (select Job, SUM(O.InvoicesReceived) InvoicesReceived, SUM(O.ContractGiven) ContractGiven from [Order] O group by Job) O on O.Job = J.id
left join (select Job, SUM(E.GrossValue) GrossValue from Estimate E group by Job) E on E.Job = J.id
left join (select Job, SUM(A.GrossValue) GrossValue from AdditionalEstimate A group by Job) A on A.Job = J.id
where (
  coalesce(O.InvoicesReceived,0) > (coalesce(E.GrossValue,0) + coalesce(A.GrossValue,0))
) OR ( 
  coalesce(O.ContractGiven,0) > (coalesce(E.GrossValue,0) + coalesce(A.GrossValue,0))
)

select [User Name], count(*)
from (
  select U.UserName [User Name], J.id
    , coalesce(O.InvoicesReceived,0) InvoicesReceived
    , coalesce(O.ContractGiven,0) ContractGiven
    , coalesce(E.GrossValue,0) + coalesce(A.GrossValue,0) TotalQuoteCost
  from Job J
  inner join [User] U on U.id = J.UserId
  left join (select Job, SUM(O.InvoicesReceived) InvoicesReceived, SUM(O.ContractGiven) ContractGiven from [Order] O group by Job) O on O.Job = J.id
  left join (select Job, SUM(E.GrossValue) GrossValue from Estimate E group by Job) E on E.Job = J.id
  left join (select Job, SUM(A.GrossValue) GrossValue from AdditionalEstimate A group by Job) A on A.Job = J.id
  where (
    coalesce(O.InvoicesReceived,0) > (coalesce(E.GrossValue,0) + coalesce(A.GrossValue,0))
  ) OR ( 
    coalesce(O.ContractGiven,0) > (coalesce(E.GrossValue,0) + coalesce(A.GrossValue,0))
  )
) x
group by [User Name]
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff2a39caf6216263d56e3332af30987d)

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate *before* you `join`:

```
select U.UserName, count(*)
from [User] U join
     Job j
     on u.id = j.userid left join
     (select o.job, sum(O.InvoicesReceived) as InvoicesReceived,
             sum(o.ContractGiven) as ContractGiven
      from [Order] O
      group by o.job
     ) o
     on o.Job = j.id left join
     (select e.job, sum(e.GrossValue) as GrossValue
      from estimate e
      group by e.job
     ) e
     on e.Job = j.id left join
     (select ae.job, sum(ae.GrossValue) as GrossValue
      from AdditionalEstimate ae
      group by ae.job
     ) ae
     on ae.Job = j.id
group by U.UserName
having coalesce(sum(o.InvoicesReceived), 0) > coalesce(sum(e.GrossValue), 0) + coalesce(sum(ae.GrossValue), 0) or
       coalesce(sum(o.ContractGiven), 0) > coalesce(sum(e.GrossValue), 0) + coalesce(sum(ae.GrossValue), 0);
```

Otherwise, the `join`s will produce a Cartesian product and the `sum()`s will be off.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fc701dfbfa58949a9140e6047460fad9) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want the jobs that meet these conditions:

```
select U.UserName, j.id
from [User] U join
     Job j
     on u.id = j.userid left join
     (select o.job, sum(O.InvoicesReceived) as InvoicesReceived,
             sum(o.ContractGiven) as ContractGiven
      from [Order] O
      group by o.job
     ) o
     on o.Job = j.id left join
     (select e.job, sum(e.GrossValue) as GrossValue
      from estimate e
      group by e.job
     ) e
     on e.Job = j.id left join
     (select ae.job, sum(ae.GrossValue) as GrossValue
      from AdditionalEstimate ae
      group by ae.job
     ) ae
     on ae.Job = j.id
where coalesce(o.InvoicesReceived, 0) > coalesce(e.GrossValue, 0) + coalesce(ae.GrossValue, 0) or
      coalesce(o.ContractGiven, 0) > coalesce(e.GrossValue, 0) + coalesce(ae.GrossValue, 0);
```

Which has [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a423f970c7718ed67dce37938dc7bb47) db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for the response.    It gives me an idea how to proceed but the results are wrong.     Updated my post so its clear what results are expected

Comment: If you run the select U.UserName, count(*) snippet it returns nothing which I presume is due to a null value eliminating the record.     Does anyone know how to fix this?